# Zipping up a shapefile

Tags: python, shapefile, compression

I know this may be a topic for Stack Overflow, but it might be worth answering here as it related to shapefiles.

I am trying to zip up a shapefile. I have selected all the components of the shapefile bar the LOCK and .CPG files. These can't be uploaded on our website for some reason, and cause a problem.

I have tried using the following code, but its keeps getting stuck in a loop and crashes ArcCatalog. I have a separate folder which can be zipped up quite easily using the shutil method. However, as I'm trying to identify files to zip, I have to use the Zipfile module.

```
rtc_shp = r"path/to/shp"

zip = zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(datafolder, "Real_Time_Closures.zip"), "w")

for f in glob.glob(rtc_shp.replace(".shp",".*")):
    if not f.endswith(".lock"):
        if not f.endswith(".cpg"):
            zip.write(f, basename(f))

shutil.make_archive(indivfolder, "zip", indivfolder)
```

Comment: Why don't you use [this script](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/sharing-workflows/h-zip-python-script.htm)? It works like a charm for me. All you have to do is add a line to exclude .cpg files from being zipped, under the existing line excluding .lock files. Also, convert the file extension to uppercase (or lowercase) to make sure you catch both case types: `if not file.upper().endswith('.LOCK'):`, `if not file.upper().endswith('.CPG'):`.

Comment: The issue is that the folder containing the shapefile, has other files in it too. So how do i edit the script you've provided to only identify these and zip them?

Comment: Depends, is `rtc_shp` a path to a shapefile, or to a folder containing a shapefile? What are the other files, are there shapefiles too? Might they have the same basename (without extension)?

Comment: I managed to stop the loop by creating an empty list, appending the file to the list, and then writing those files to the zip file.

Comment: This is really "how to zip up a group of files" which I think is more suited to [so].

Comment: I do mention that at the beginning of the post, but as it's to do with shapefiles, I thought it might be useful for the GIS community

Comment: I guess the voting will tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bypassed the loop by creating an empty list and then appending the filenames to the list. I then wrote the contents of the list to the zip file.

```
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(datafolder, "MMO_Real_Time_Closures.zip"), "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

shp_zip_list = []

for f in glob.glob(rtc_shp.replace(".shp",".*")):
    if not f.endswith(".lock"):
        if not f.endswith(".cpg"):
            shp_zip_list.append(f)

for f in shp_list:
    zip.write(f, basename(f))

zip.close()

shutil.make_archive(indivfolder, "zip", indivfolder)
```